# Openpyxl - set column format in iter_cols()

Tags: python, format, openpyxl

I think this might be useful not only for myself. Every column in Excel file has certain format. So I iterate over columns, get their names and pass to the functions, which returns array with format values. I would like to set this format for the entire column.

Here is my code:

```
# will return values by column name
def get_format(name):
    ...
    return {'width' : 14, 'align' : 'centre'} #just default for test

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'/test_format.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet']
for col in ws.iter_cols():
    format_col = get_format(col[0].value)
#     then should apply the format for entire column
```

Could you, please, help me, how to make this?

UPD. The question is: how to apply the format in iter_cols loop? I know about styles etc., but my attempts like:

```
col.width = format_col['width']
```

were of course unsuccessful.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: It sounds like openpyxl.styles is what you want, https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html You can create styles and then assign them to a whole column

Comment: I think you're confusing "column dimensions" (width, hidden, grouping) and cell formatting. Cell formatting **must** be applied to every cell individually. Just copy the style.

Answer (score 0):

*If I understand you*, this will apply the **copied format** for the **entire column**.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'/test_format.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet']
for col in ws.iter_cols():    
    format_col = col[0]._style # will get the column header formating
    
    # then apply the format for entire column
    for cell in col:  
        cell._style = format_col   

wb.save(r'/test_format.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: It's not advisable to use the private attribute. Always better to copy the style. Better still to use named styles.